# Grid within frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a grid structure in python tinker that is positioned aside each other without any free space in between, but I am somehow not able to achieve this.

Could anyone help in what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("700x600")
frame1=tk.Frame(window,width=350,height=400,bg='black')
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=1,columnspan=1)


frame2=tk.Frame(window,width=350,height=600,bg='white')
frame2.grid(row=0,column=1)

frame3=tk.Frame(window,width=350,height=200,bg='red')
frame3.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=1,columnspan=1)


window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Here is the Output that I am getting, though what I want is that the black frame and red frame fit together without any gap in between, so that the overall height remains 600.

Comment: Try changing `frame2.grid(row=0,column=1)` to `frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because `frame2` in the second column is taller than `frame1` to the left of it. To workaround that, simply specify that it spans both rows that `frame1` and `frame3` occupy.

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("700x600")

frame1=tk.Frame(window, width=350, height=400, bg='black')
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)

frame2=tk.Frame(window, width=350, height=600, bg='white')
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2)  # Added rowspan here.

frame3=tk.Frame(window, width=350, height=200, bg='red')
frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of result]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `rowspan` argument in `frame2`.

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("700x600")
frame1 = tk.Frame(window, width=350, height=400, bg='black')
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)

frame2 = tk.Frame(window, width=350, height=600, bg='white')
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2) # here add rowspan = 2 argument

frame3 = tk.Frame(window, width=350, height=200, bg='red')
frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)


window.mainloop()
```

This is happening because you are having 2 frames on the left side both taking one row itself (2 rows total), and you need to span the right white frame to 2 rows to get the grid layout you want (to make them equal on right and left), otherwise it gets messed up because of difference between the number of frames in column 0 (2) and number of frames in column 1 (1).

[image: Output you get after changing the code.]